# empathy can't connect to facebook chat

Tags: empathy

I am using ubuntu 12.10, and when I try to connect to my Facebook account through Empathy, it gets disconnected and says this account is already connected to the server.

Comment: Please add more information (screenshots and the like) to help the community answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to grant application access for Facebook account](/q/714573)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did and it worked perfectly so maybe it would work for you. I just deleted the account and added it again. The Ubuntu did the rest  automatically for me (asked for email / login and password). Now it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually conecting to Facebook chat, as it's really a **jabber** server. Set up a new **XMPP/Jabber** account. Use this settings:

- **User Name**: Your Facebook username (your url, such as *http://www.facebook.com/my.username*.
- **Domain**: `chat.facebook.com`
- **Jabber identifier**: `your.username@chat.facebook.com`
- **Password**: Your facebook passsword.
- **Server**: `chat.facebook.com`
- **Port**: `5222`
- **Use SSL/TLS**: `Yes`

If asked, use `plain text` as autentication.

Hope it helps you! For more information, check [Facebook's chat page](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php).

Comment: this options not available in empathy but i try it in pidgin and get the same problem

Comment: It worked flawlessly for me, thanks! Using, Ubuntu 14.04.1, Pidgin 2.10.9

Answer (score 1):

Other people have also been having this issue on other chat clients, such as pidgin and trillian. I think facebook may have changed something, although some people seem to have it back up. 
Here's some posts that are related, hopefully this helps
http://www.ceruleanstudios.com/forums/showthread.php?p=854491